# useState place in lifecycle in react

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-lifecycle-hooks

I really want to understand  the lifecycle of react functional component. In many websites you see these three steps:
1-mounthing 2-render 3-unmounthing.

But what about other code that is written before useeffect() function for example assume this:

```
const Countdown = () => {
  let x = 0;
  const [countDown, setCountDown] = useState(10)
   
   x = x + 1
   
   if(x > 100) { 
     x = 0
   }

  useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
        setCountDown(countDown - 1);
        console.log(x)
      }, 1000);
    }, [countDown]);
};
```

I want to know :

1. when countDown state and x variable is declared before useEffect or after it (or inside it)?
2. when `if` or `for`  phrases is declared(in this example `if` phrase), Are they inside useEffect indeed?

what is loading page order? what is start point of executing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### The lifecycle

> 1-mounthing 2-render 4-unmounthing.

It's more like ([docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html)):

- **Mount**

  - **Render** *(React calls your component function)*
  - **Commit** to DOM *(React reconciles elements with the DOM)*
  - **Layout effects** *(React calls relevant layout effect callbacks scheduled via [`useLayoutEffect`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#uselayouteffect))*
  - **Effects** *(React calls relevant non-layout effect callbacks scheduled via [`useEffect`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect)))*
- **Update** (repeats)

  - **Render** *(React calls your component function)*
  - **Commit** to DOM *(React reconciles elements with the DOM)*
  - **Layout effects** *(React calls relevant layout effect callbacks scheduled via `useLayoutEffect`)*
  - **Effects** *(React calls relevant non-layout effect callbacks scheduled via `useEffect`))*
  - **Cleanup** if any *(React React calls any effect cleanup callbacks)*
- **Unmount**

  - **Removal** *(React removes elements from the DOM)*
  - **Cleanup** if any *(React React calls any effect cleanup callbacks)*

### Your Questions

> when countDown state and x variable is declared before useEffect or after it (or inside it)?

Before. The React library can't change how JavaScript code execution occurs. The `useState` call and associated declarations are before the `useEffect` call, so they happen before it.

> when if or for phrases is declared(in this example if phrase), Are they inside useEffect indeed?

No, only the code within the `useEffect` callback is called as an effect.

### How your code runs

The cycle here is:

1. First render

   1. React creates behind-the-scenes instance storage for the element.
   2. React calls your component function.

      1. Your code declares a local `x` variable and sets it to `0`.
      2. Your code declares `countDown` and `setCountDown` and calls `useState`, which allocates a state slot in the instance storage; your code stores what `useState` returns (the initial state value and the setter) in those constants.
      3. Your `x = x + 1` statement runs, updating `x` to `1`.
      4. Your `if` statement runs, but the condition will never be true — `x` is a local variable, not a state member, so its value will always be `1` at this point.
      5. Your call to `useEffect` schedules an effect callback for when `countDown` changes.
      6. At this point, your code should be returning elements from `Countdown`.
2. First commit / "mount"

   1. React takes the elements `Countdown` should return and *commits* them to the DOM (making the DOM show what they describe).
3. React calls your `useEffect` callback (`useEffect` callbacks are always called just after mount)

   1. Your callback creates an interval timer that, when run, will call `setCountDown`.
   2. Your callback logs `x`, which will be `1`.
4. The timer calls `setCountDown`, changing the value.
5. Second render

   1. React calls your function to re-render.

      1. Your code declares a new local `x` variable and sets it to `0`.
      2. Your code declares `countDown` and `setCountDown` and calls `useState`, which retrieves the updated state from the instance storage; your code stores what `useState` returns (the current state value and the setter) in those constants.
      3. Your `x = x + 1` statement runs, updating `x` to `1`.
      4. Your `if` statement runs, but the condition will never be true.
      5. Your call to `useEffect` schedules an effect callback for when `countDown` changes.
      6. At this point, your code should be returning elements from `Countdown`.
6. Because `countDown` changed, React calls your `useEffect` callback

   1. Your callback creates a new interval timer that, when run, will call `setCountDown`.
   2. Your callback logs `x`, which will be `1`.
7. And so on until/unless the component is umounted by its parent.

### Issues with the code

There are a couple of bugs in the code you've shown

1. You never cancel the interval timer, but you're creating a new one every time `countDown` changes. This will quickly lead to hundreds and then thousands of timers all triggering update calls. You should:

   1. At minimum, remember the timer handle and cancel the timer in an effect cleanup.
   2. Consider not using `countDown` as a dependency, so the effect only runs on mount. Then use the callback form of `setCountDown`.
2. (As mentioned) Your component never returns any elements
3. Your code seemed to expect the value of `x` to be maintained between calls to the function, but it's a local variable, so it's re-created each time.
4. Nothing special happens when `countDown` reaches `0`, so it will just keep going to `-1`, `-2`, etc.

### Updated version

Here's an updated version with some notes. I was going to remove `x` because it wasn't really used for anything, but then thought it might be better to leave it with comments. And I didn't do anything about #4 above, because I wasn't sure what you wanted to do.

```
const Countdown = () => {
    let x = 0;
    const [countDown, setCountDown] = useState(10);

    x = x + 1;
    if (x > 100) {  // `x` will always be `1` here, remember that
        x = 0;      // `x` is a *local variable*
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        const interval = setInterval(() => {
            // Use the callback form of the setter so you can update the
            // up-to-date value
            setCountDown((c) => c - 1);
            // Will always show 1
            console.log(x);
        }, 1000);
        // Return a cleanup callback that removes the interval timer
        return () => {
            clearInterval(interval);
        };
    }, []);
    // ^^ don't use `countDown` as a dependency (in this particular case),
    // since we don't use it (anymore, now we use the callback setter)

    // Return some elements
    return <div>{countDown}</div>;
};
```

```js
const { useState, useEffect } = React;

const Countdown = () => {
    let x = 0;
    const [countDown, setCountDown] = useState(10);

    x = x + 1;
    if (x > 100) {  // `x` will always be `1` here, remember that
        x = 0;      // `x` is a *local variable*
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        const interval = setInterval(() => {
            // Use the callback form of the setter so you can update the
            // up-to-date value
            setCountDown((c) => c - 1);
            // Will always show 1
            console.log(x);
        }, 1000);
        // Return a cleanup callback that removes the interval timer
        return () => {
            clearInterval(interval);
        };
    }, []);
    // ^^ don't use `countDown` as a dependency (in this particular case),
    // since we don't use it (anymore, now we use the callback setter)

    // Return some elements
    return <div>{countDown}</div>;
};

const Example = () => {
    return <Countdown />;
};

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(<Example />);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.1.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.1.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

If we wanted the countdown to stop when it reached `0` and turn off the timer, there are a couple of ways we might do that, see comments in the two live examples showing different ways:

```js
const { useState, useEffect } = React;

const Countdown = () => {
    const [countDown, setCountDown] = useState(10);

    useEffect(() => {
        const interval = setInterval(() => {
            // We could cancel the interval from within the setter
            // callback. It's a bit dodgy, though, to have side-
            // effects in setter callbacks.
            setCountDown((c) => {
                const updated = c - 1;
                if (updated === 0) {
                    clearInterval(interval);
                }
                return updated;
            });
        }, 1000);
        return () => {
            clearInterval(interval);
        };
    }, []);

    return <div>{countDown === 0 ? "Done" : countDown}</div>;
};

const Example = () => {
    return <Countdown />;
};

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(<Example />);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.1.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.1.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

```js
const { useState, useEffect, useRef } = React;

const Countdown = () => {
    // We could store the timer handle in a ref (which is maintained
    // across renders) and use a second `useEffect` to cancel it when
    // `countDown` reaches zero.
    const intervalRef = useRef(0);
    const [countDown, setCountDown] = useState(10);

    useEffect(() => {
        intervalRef.current = setInterval(() => {
            setCountDown((c) => c - 1);
        }, 1000);
        return () => {
            // (It's okay if this tries to clear an interval that
            // isn't running anymore.)
            clearInterval(intervalRef.current);
        };
    }, []);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (countDown === 0) {
            clearInterval(intervalRef.current);
        }
    }, [countDown]);

    return <div>{countDown === 0 ? "Done" : countDown}</div>;
};

const Example = () => {
    return <Countdown />;
};

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(<Example />);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.1.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.1.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

***useEffec's place in the lifecycle***

It doesn't matter where you put a `useEffect` in your component code, all effects will always run **after** every render. The only time the `useEffect` place in the component's code might be important is if you have multiple `useEffect`s, as they will execute by the order you've written them.

***x variable/state***

As for your `x` variable, this is not something that would work in react because that variable will be redeclared on every render. The way you keep track of state is by using the `useState`. I would argue you could track both values from the same state but  if you want to have ab additional explicit state, you need to use another `useState` hook. The general convention is that
state hooks are declared at the top of the component (but they don't have to).

***if statements***

One of the **[rules of react hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html)** is that all hooks must run on every render. You can still use id statements in your components and custom hooks but they either have to run **after** all the hooks in your component, or you can declare then **within** your hook - that way the hook executes on every render but the code block inside it will run only when the if statement's condition was true.

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (condition) {
    code to run...
  }
}, [countDown]);
```

***additional notes***

Another important thing to remember about `useEffect`s is that sometimes they need to be cleaned up with a return statement. In your case you are declaring an interval, without a returning a `clearInterval` your `useEffect` will create an additional interval on every render which will cause your counter to get out of sync